# Getting latest date for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time getting the latest results for various records in SQL Server 2008. I'm trying to use MAX(), but it is only returning a few results when there should be over 1,000.

EDIT: The results include computer names and the last usage information. It is for software metering results for SCCM. The line "mf.SecurityKey = 'CSA00107'" is basically just looking for software metering results for Microsoft Visio. However, there are various instances of "Last Used" dates for each computer. I need the LAST "Last Used" date so there is one last usage record for each computer name.

Query:

```
select distinct vrs.Name0,mus.LastUsage
from v_MeteredFiles mf
     inner join v_MonthlyUsageSummary mus on mus.FileID = mf.MeteredFileID
     left outer join v_R_System vrs on vrs.ResourceID = mus.ResourceID
where mf.SecurityKey = 'CSA00107' and
      DateDiff(day, mus.LastUsage, GetDate()) > 60 and
      mus.LastUsage in (select max(LastUsage) from v_MonthlyUsageSummary group by ResourceID)
```

When I remove the last line, I receive all of the results. However, since there are various "LastUsage" records for a single "Name0", I'm getting too many results. I need the LATEST LastUsage for each machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You should provide sample data and desire output.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but does `ResourceID` in the `v_MonthlyUsageSummary` table correspond 1:1 with a machine name? if not, then I suspect you are grouping by the wrong column in your `sub-query`.

Comment: Yes - ResourceID corresponds with machine name. It is what I use as a unique ID for joining the majority of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` function instead of a `sub-query`.

```
select Name0, LastUsage 
from (
select vrs.Name0, mus.LastUsage,
row_number() over(partition by vrs.Name0 order by mus.lastusage desc) as rn
from v_MeteredFiles mf
inner join v_MonthlyUsageSummary mus on mus.FileID = mf.MeteredFileID
left outer join v_R_System vrs on vrs.ResourceID = mus.ResourceID
where mf.SecurityKey = 'CSA00107' and
DateDiff(day, mus.LastUsage, GetDate()) > 60 ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Edit : As per OP's request in the comments

```
select Name0, LastUsage 
from (
select vrs.Name0, mus.LastUsage,
row_number() over(partition by vrs.Name0 order by mus.lastusage desc) as rn
from v_MeteredFiles mf
inner join v_MonthlyUsageSummary mus on mus.FileID = mf.MeteredFileID
left outer join v_R_System vrs on vrs.ResourceID = mus.ResourceID
where mf.SecurityKey = 'CSA00107' ) t
where rn = 1 
and DateDiff(day, LastUsage, GetDate()) > 60
```

Comment: It looks like this is working perfectly. However, the performance is pretty bad. I'm at 7 minutes now with 5,000 rows.

Comment: Actually, this does not appear to be working. It is picking the older record out of the two. For instance, one machine has the following last usage records: 2014-09-15 15:54:22.000 and 2015-09-08 18:18:21.000. Your query is selecting the older of the two (2014-09-15).

Comment: The results need to show only computer names and the last usage date for computers that have not had a last usage (latest last usage) in over 60 days. Is that DateDiff line causing an issue?

Comment: set up a fiddle with sample data. without seeing data, i can only guess

Comment: Not sure what a fiddle is. Here is the issue. With my old query, I would come up with HOSTNAME1 with 6 different records with various "Last Used" dates. With your query, I receive one record for HOSTNAME1, but the last used date is not the newest (or oldest) in some cases. For one particular machine I am looking at now, it is showing the middle date for "last used." More specifically: "2015-06-25 22:33:32.000" when the last used date should be "2015-09-11 19:24:27.000." The first record for "last used" for that machine is "2015-03-18 22:19:13.000" just for your reference.

Comment: the `where` clause is the problem. you are getting dates where datediff is > 60. Use `< 60` instead. Or better remove that condition, as you will always get the latest date with the query

Comment: I don't want the latest date in the actual results. I want to show all machines that have NOT used the software in over 60 days. In order to do that, I need the latest "last used" date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `in` with `=`

And internal Select need reference to outside value.

```
select distinct vrs.Name0,mus.LastUsage
from v_MeteredFiles mf
inner join v_MonthlyUsageSummary mus 
     on mus.FileID = mf.MeteredFileID
left outer join v_R_System vrs 
     on vrs.ResourceID = mus.ResourceID
where mf.SecurityKey = 'CSA00107' 
  and DateDiff(day, mus.LastUsage, GetDate()) > 60 
  and mus.LastUsage **=** (select max(LastUsage) 
                           from v_MonthlyUsageSummary IMUS
                         **where IMUS.ResourceID = mus.ResourceID**)
```